# How to use capital case characters with spaces in string.xml naming?

Tags: android

I have an excel sheet of like 1000+ rows containing string values for different languages. But the key used in that excel is named like "WL 1.1" and so on.
This same key is being used to name audio and image files like "WL 1.1.mp3".

I can make the audio files work by using the asset folder but this name "WL 1.1" is not compatible according to resource naming convention. So what should i do now?

and defining 1000 string values for every language will consume a lot of time so is there any workaround for this?

Comment: so you have defined 1000+ string without knowing if the format was correct?

Comment: no, i mean i have to define

Comment: WL_1.1 is correct or WL1.1, you have to rename all the strings

Comment: @KKKKK I have edited the question, please read.

Comment: maybe there is a way to remove all the spaces between words in your excel sheet

Comment: =SUBSTITUTE(B1," ","") for example

Comment: in this way when you get the string from excel to android you get a string without spaces

Comment: What do you think about this solution?

Comment: so you mean to say i should directly use excel sheet in android app or should i manually write the strings.xml ?

Comment: I mean to use directly the excel sheet in your android app, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41523921/read-excel-file-in-android-java

Comment: save your 1000+ string in some structure and use it for your purpose